# Webservice change method response without notifying clients

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, wsdl, asmx

Let's assume I have a webservice which returns a class on all methods, informing the client the status of the process, for example:

```
public class WsResult {

  string result; // either "error" or "ok"

}
```

Now we'd like to add a property to this class, without forcing all clients consuming our service to update their software. Is this possible?

For example:

```
public class WsResult {

  public string result; // either "error" or "ok"

  public Guid? someIdentifier;

}
```

I'm looking for answers on both WCF and ASMX.

Comment: Is this wcf or asmx?

Comment: @TomRedfern I'd like an answer for both, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**WCF**

It is possible. You can simply add a new property and it'll work providing that this new property is not required. For more details see point 8 of [Best Practices: Data Contract Versioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832.aspx) article.

If you need to handle round-tripping scenario you should read about `IExtensibleDataObject` interface. Round-tripping occurs when data is sent from a server to a client and it is expected that it'll be sent back. See [Forward-Compatible Data Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx) article for details.

**ASMX**

With ASMX a situation is the same. You can add a new property and all clients should work. In this case you can also use `IExtensibleDataObject` interface.

**Final Comments**

This answer is based on empirical tests with VS 2015. I strongly suggest you to do the same i.e.: write simple WCF/ASMX servers and clients and verify behaviour described by me. It took me just several minutes to do so. Or even better you can use already existing services.

I recommend additional tests because you may be using some non-default configuration which changes the default behaviour of WCF/ASMX services so it is better to check. I'm not aware of this kind of configuration but you never know.

Answer (score -1):

With WCF you can actually have different classes on the client and server side, which is what will normally happen as well when using the **Add service reference** UI. The trick to make this work is to set the namespace and the name on the `DataContract` attribute (and perhaps even the name on the `DataMember` attribute if the member names differ).

Only the properties that match will be deserialized, as such adding a property on the server side won't impact the client side.